# How to find neighbors within a distance for an unconnected node within a networkx python graph

Tags: networkx

I would like to simulate a wireless network with time-varying and mobile behaviour of the nodes. Thus, I need every time that the node wakes up or moves **to search for its neighbours within a distance**. How can I find the nearby nodes? There exist any functions?  Thank you

Comment: are you after a topological distance or a geometric distance? context of WSN indicates maybe is physical distance, rather than number of edges you need to traverse.  But the question is not clear. (Current answers read it as topological distance)

Comment: @Bonlenfum Updated my answer to address this.

Comment: If any of these answers addressed your question, you should mark the most helpful one with the checkbox beside it. This helps future users who also have your question.

Answer (score 2):

It's a single function: [`ego_graph`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.generators.ego.ego_graph.html). It lets you specify a distance parameter, called the `radius`.

```
import networkx as nx

# Sample data
G = nx.florentine_families_graph()
nx.draw_networkx(G, with_labels=True)

# Desired graph
H = nx.ego_graph(G, node=4, radius=2)
nx.draw_networkx(H, with_labels=True)
```

The entire Florentine families graph:

[image: florentine_families_graph]

And just those within distance 2 of the node 'Acciauoli':

[image: acciauoli ego graph]

If you're using a distance measure other than simple topological distance (i.e. counting edges), you can provide the `distance` parameter to the `ego_graph` function to specify an edge attribute to use for distance.

Comment: 2.8.4 version uses `n` instead of `node` parameter